# How can one get this texture or background on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, maps

Please take a look at this implementation of http://map.embed.ly/ [google maps][1] . Would like to know how it can be achieved ? I have seen only satellite, hybrid implementation this seems new to me

Ankur

Comment: The link in you question is corrupted.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing it out Argiropoulos Stavros I have now updated the link.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a well done custom overlay on top of Google Maps API (v3).

The GMAP API website has an [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#Drawing) that shows the code as well as the [output](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-simple.html). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking at doing is implementing the Google Maps API. It provides methods for placing custom overlays and data sets into a Google Maps interface:

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html